# When Creating DNN module getting Web Server Error

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

Hi I am getting error when adding new dot nuke project module template

[image]

Comment: How do you expect us to help you with one tiny line of text and a useless screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Try running visual studio as an administrator, and also make sure you add "dnndev.me" as a binding on your IIS website.